# Visual Studio 2010 error: "Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.Databases' cannot be used like a method."

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I get the following error when compiling a simple C# console app from MSDN docs, [Setting Up a Partition Scheme for a Table in Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162136.aspx):

```
Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.Databases' 
cannot be used like a method.
```

The offending line:

```
//Reference the AdventureWorks2008R2 database.  
db = srv.Databases("AdventureWorks2008R2");
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

p.s. To compile this, I created a console app, as described at [How to: Create a Visual C# SMO Project in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2008R2"];`

Databases is a property that returns a DatabaseCollection, not a method. You then use the default indexer of DatabaseCollection to get your database.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.databases.aspx).

Your linked page appears to have an mistake.